# Install jar with dependencies to maven repository (Android gcm-server push library)

Tags: java, android, maven, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I work on an industrialized large maven project, and on an application module, I need to be able to send push notifications to Android (with new Google Cloud Messaging).

It seems google provide themselves the server-side library to send the notifications, and according to the mailing list they do not provide any maven repository.

The first step mentionned in the google documentation is:

```
Copy the gcm-server.jar file from the SDK's gcm-server/dist directory to your server classpath.
```

I'm not going to do that so i've added the jar to my local repository and will add it to our enterprise Nexus.

```
mvn install:install-file
 -Dfile=gcm-server.jar
 -Dsources=gcm-server-sources.jar
 -DgroupId=com.google.android.gcm
 -DartifactId=gcm-server
 -Dversion=r3
 -DgeneratePom=true
 -Dpackaging=jar
```

But i've just noticed that the library has dependencies (simple-json, mockito and junit).
It's not precised if they are runtime or tests but i guess only simple-json is used at runtime.
I think retrieving the GCM dependency from our Nexus should also permit to retrieve the transitive dependencies like this simple-json lib right?

Thus what am i supposed to do? Should i create on my own a pom file for a project i don't own, and then import the project to my maven repository with `-DpomFile=my-custom-pom.xml`?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally i've ended creating my own pom.

I've created a maven repository on github here:
https://github.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository

Thus anyone can download this jar with maven and also its transitive dependencies.

I've added the files/commands so that you know how i've done.

Add repository:

```
<repository>
    <id>gcm-server-repository</id>
    <url>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository/master/releases/</url>
</repository>
```

And dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gcm</groupId>
    <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How often is this being updated? Where is the v1.0.2 version number from?

Comment: @Amorgos I don't know at all but people never gave me any feedback so I guess the deployed version is still ok. I've found this version number in an ant script that was with google jar I think

Comment: This library is little outdated. It does not have the method builder.restrictedPackageName(PACKAGE_NAME);

Comment: Note github has changed its domain, so the repository url is now probably `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository/master/releases/`

Answer (score 3):

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-gcm/oukjcHpbLj4/lql_IzpjmUkJ%5B1-25%5D.

It seems that google simply doesn't publish this jar in any maven repository. You have two options:

1. Include all (transitively) dependent jars in your repository
2. (like you said) Create your own pom file

I would go for the second option. It's not that hard.

Comment: The google group link is broken but it's probably the topic i mention in my initial question. I'll try to create the pom, for this project it will be pretty easy thanks

Answer (score 3):

Works using:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gcm</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

And

```
<repository>
        <id>gcm-server-repository</id>
        <url>https://github.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository/raw/master/releases/</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux or Mac, you may use the following script saved as mvn-intall-jar:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script to mavenize any JAR files
# by Muhammad Ichsan <ichsan@gmail.com>
#

desc=$1
binary=$2
source=$3

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage $0 <DESCRIPTION> <BINARY JAR FILE> [SOURCE JAR FILE]"
    echo "e.g. $0 com.google.android.gcm/gcm-server/2.1.4 gcm-server.jar gcm-server-src.jar"
    exit 1
fi

groupId=`echo $desc | awk -F '/' '{print $1}'`
artifactId=`echo $desc | awk -F '/' '{print $2}'`
version=`echo $desc | awk -F '/' '{print $3}'`

if [ "$version" = "" ]; then
    echo "Invalid DESCRIPTION"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$source" != "" ]; then
    mvn install:install-file\
 -Dfile=$binary\
 -DgroupId=$groupId\
 -DartifactId=$artifactId\
 -Dversion=$version\
 -DgeneratePom=true\
 -Dpackaging=jar\
 -Dsources=$source
else
    mvn install:install-file\
 -Dfile=$binary\
 -DgroupId=$groupId\
 -DartifactId=$artifactId\
 -Dversion=$version\
 -DgeneratePom=true\
 -Dpackaging=jar
fi
```

And use this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gcm</groupId>
    <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This works but will not include the transitive dependency required by GCM which is json-simple 1.1, meaning you should already have json-simple in your classpath, or add it additionnally yourself to your application dependencies

Comment: JARs without dependency information require manual dependency handling. The case is like old time when Ant was used by most people then. You must know what JARs a JAR depends on. I believe creating your own pom file will meet your need.